# Switching Client and Server roles on gRPC in .NET Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

So I'm starting with the simple Greeter service from the VS2022 sample project template "ASP.NET Core gRPC Service", targeting .NET7, running on Windows. Name this side "A".

I was able to write a second console app (also .NET7) that connects as a gRPC client to that service, invoke the SayHello() rpc successfully and retrieve the expected response message. Name this side "B". So far, so good.

My scenario, however, is a bit different: I want the client *B* to connect to the server *A* and authenticate with the server (which is not part of the sample so far but I assume this will work fine as well). Then, the server *A* shall start acting as a gRPC client and the console-app-client *B* shall act as a gRPC server, i.e. I want them to switch roles (or establish another role if you like). The challenge is that I want the two parties to re-use the same TCP HTTP/2 connection that has already been established. So I'm looking for a way to create new instances of gRPC client/servers at runtime and provide them with the existing TCP connection. The reason why I need to do it this way are limitations coming from network security (the initial connection can only come *B* to *A*). I'm aware that by using streams I can make my server *A* send messages to *B*, but I'd prefer to have the full client/server support.

I saw a few discussions around the same question but the presented approaches are using GO as a language and it's hard for me to understand whether and how I can do the same in .NET7.

Possible? Thanks!

Comment: This is basically a feature called "gRPC tunneling" which is something we envisioned long time ago, but it never got implemented https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14101

Comment: I think in principle you could implement this on your own, but it's quite involved. You'd basically need to create a long-lived bidi streaming RPC that would act as a "tunnel" and then you'd need a custom grpc transport that can establish connections over the stream abstraction provided by the underlying RPC.  You'd have to investigate whether grpc-dotnet currently exposes enough of internals to provide a custom transport like this (that a server could listen on and a client could connect to it).